# How to mock an ATL COM object in googletest unit tests

Tags: c++, com, googletest, atl, googlemock

I am working on a legacy project that makes massive use of ATL COM objects. The task is to extend the unit testing (googletest) by the capability of mocking COM objects, or the smart pointers accessing them. To illustrate, I created a small example project with a single `ATL simple object`, which only exports the method `methodB` (part of idl file):

```cpp
    object,
    uuid(070a4996-d9cf-4434-a823-3ea9043de394),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyATLObj : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT methodB([in] SHORT in, [out, retval] SHORT *out);
};
```

The objects are accessed using smart pointers of base type `_com_ptr_t`, such as in this example:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#include ".../ATLExample_i.h"

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMyATLObj, __uuidof(IMyATLObj));

IMyATLObjPtr create() {
    IMyATLObjPtr objPtr;
    objPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyATLObj));
        
    return objPtr;
}

void use(IMyATLObjPtr objPtr) {
    short val = 0;

    objPtr->methodB(1, &val);

    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Now the question is how I can test the function `use(...)` without actually creating a COM object. Of course I can create a wrapper class as a facade to all COM interactions that I can mock as usual, e.g.:

```
class MyObjFacade {
public:
  MyObjFacade() {
    objPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyATLObj));
  }

  virtual short methodB(short in) {
    short val;
    if (objPtr->methodB(in, &val) == S_OK)
      return val;
    else
      throw;
  }

  IMyATLObjPtr objPtr;
};

class MYObjMock : public MyObjFacade {
public: 
  MOCK_METHOD1(methodB, short(short in));
};
```

---

```
    void use(MyObjFacade *objPtr) {
      short val = 0;

      val = objPtr->methodB(1);

      std::cout << val << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
```

---

```
    TEST_F(COMMockTest, Test1) {
      MYObjMock mock;

      EXPECT_CALL(mock, methodB(_)).WillOnce(Return(43));

      use(&mock);
    }
```

But that would obviously leave me with lots of boiler plate code and (possibly) unnessessary changes - this solution would probably not be well adopted. I am looking for an elegant solution that, for example, either introduces a mock object into `IMyATLObjPtr` mocks the pointer object itself. However, I don't really know where to start because all the available interfaces are generated by ATL and are not easily accessible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you address why you don't just create the COM object ?  As `use` performs an action on the COM object it looks like the real object is necessary to validate the correct performance of `use`.

Comment: The COM objects are large and require a substantial amount of infrastructure, loading files, communicating externally, GUI, etc., which I would like to reduce for isolated tests. Of course the `std::cout`s are not a very interesting thing to test, but I wanted to keep it brief in the example.

Comment: "all the available interfaces are generated by ATL and are not easily accessible." ATL is 100% open source, so you can see exactly what is in there. Also note comdef.h (_com_ptr_t, etc.) is not provided by ATL

Comment: @SimonMourier Ok, that might have been misleading. I was referring to anything COM-related. I don't see how I could _change_ or _replace_ something without breaking the whole thing.

Comment: COM interfaces are 100% binary contract (vtable), usually (it's not strictly mandatory) materialized by metadata  information called a Type Library (a .tlb file or the same embedded as a Win32 resource, etc.) generated from an .idl file. This type library is programmable itself (through the ITypeLib interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-itypelib) so COM interfaces are good candidates to mocking, but it's a lot of work. I don't know any out-of-the-shelve tooling.